# How to fix a exact size to Tkinter.Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I am working with Tkinter.Canvas of python.When I add or change texts of labels inside a canvas, canvas changes its width. I searched in Canvas class also but I can't find any way to fix a width to canvas exactly. If anyone know how to do it, please answer.

Comment: How can we help without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Creating text items on a canvas will not change its size. Properly adding a label with `create_window` also shouldn't change its size.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `tk.Canvas(width=800, height=800)`